# issue while creating connection to hadoop in talend big data

Tags: hadoop, connection, etl, talend, bigdata

I am facing issue while creating connection to Hadoop in Talend Big Data. I want to establish Hortonworks connection inside Talend. I have Hortonworks sandbox also, but the problem I am getting is Ambari server is not running. It is showing `Unable to start PostgreSQL server` error.

```
ERROR: Exiting with exit code 1. 
REASON: Unable to start PostgreSQL server. Status None....Exiting
```

1. When I checked for `service postgresql status` it is showing :

   `postmaster dead but pid file exists.`
2. While trying to opening Ambari Ui through browser it is asking for
   username and password but not accepting it.

Comment: Have you [seen this post](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/12219/ambari-server-not-running.html)?

Comment: yes i have already gone through the mentioned post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering it is a virtual machine side issue I have deleted the exiting machine in hortonworks virtual box and recreated the new one with different configuration

1. Now restart the machine
2. Check **"service ambari-server status"** and **"service postgresql status"** in shell.

It's working fine for me. This might be because sometimes virtual box has not properly shutdown or power off.

But Still I am not able to open the Ambari server in browser, even after giving crendentials. Please suggest.